# Sending HTTP Request to call Google Sheet API to edit a cell

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to make a webpage that takes data from URL query and write them into a Google spread sheet. What I tried is make a Atom.xml and link it in my HTML code and use

```
     XMLHttpRequest().setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/atom+xml")
```

In my JavaScript code.

My question is simple, how should I send this request with the `<entry>...</entry>` that Google asks me to have in the 'body' of this PUT request?

I've read the Sheet API Document and searched on Google for a long time but no result. I have no idea how to have a 'body' for the PUT request.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with XMLHttpRequest.  I acknowledge that this is not the answer you're looking for; however, I think this is useful to anyone whom may stumble across this, and may be useful for you.

People typically use a framework with their websites like jquery or angularjs.

https://jquery.com/
In jquery you can do a put request with a body as follows:

```
var xmldata = '<some xml... >';

$.ajax({
    method: "PUT",
    url: "some_url",
    contentType: 'application/atom+xml'
    data: xmldata
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
})
.fail(function(e){
    console.log("There was a problem!");
    console.log(e);
})
.always(function(d) {
    console.log("This will always happen!");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Consider using a tool like this because it makes your code simpler and easier to read.  And most relevant: it saves you time and effort.

**Edit** to elaborate on the callbacks of the promise and the parameters:

> jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {}); An alternative
>   construct to the success callback option, the .done() method replaces
>   the deprecated jqXHR.success() method. Refer to deferred.done() for
>   implementation details.
>
> jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {}); An
>   alternative construct to the error callback option, the .fail() method
>   replaces the deprecated .error() method. Refer to deferred.fail() for
>   implementation details.
>
> jqXHR.always(function( data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown ) {
>   }); An alternative construct to the complete callback option, the
>   .always() method replaces the deprecated .complete() method.

From: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: See my disclaimer at the top of my post whomever down-voted.  If there is something incorrect about my post please let me know.  I stand by this being useful information to consider.

Comment: Ok, but what about the 'body'? The <entry> tag?

Comment: @DavidXu Um... yes, the 'xmldata' variable I passed into the data field of the ajax request object should be a string of xml like '<entry>blah</entry' or something.

Comment: I tried this but not working :( Nothing just happens and the .done function never gets executed. Why? I did import the jQuery library. I put the entry tag in the xmldata.

Comment: @DavidXu My apologies, I should have included fail and always in the original answer.  Try this and see what prints out.

Comment: Thanks. I marked yours as the answer because it works now. @csga5000 By the way, the old one didn't work not because your answer, but because the problem of my jQuery library.